# How to check if the logged in user is present in groups in class based views(viewsets.ModelViewSet)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I have a class based view

```
class JobViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

I have 2 group of users(implemented using django.contrib.auth.models Group), 'company' and 'customer'.
On each view, I have to check if the user belongs to a certain group.
Is it possible to do it using custom permission_classes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can see that [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#examples)
Something like :

```
class IsCompany(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Check if user is in company group
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        user = request.user
        is_company = user.groups.filter(name='company')
        return is_company
```